# Google Chrome App Shortcuts don't work

Tags: google-chrome

When I create app shortcuts in Google Chrome, the shortcut icons appear, but they don't work. Any idea why? I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and Chrome 28.0.1500.29 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening up the created `.desktop` files in a text editor displays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Gmail
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome --app-id=pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia --profile-directory=Default
Icon=chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia
```

When running the command `/opt/google/chrome/chrome --app-id=pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia --profile-directory=Default`, however, I get the error:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Examining the file `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`, which ships with Chrome, indicates that the correct executable path is `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`, not `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`. So the problem can be fixed by editing the created `.desktop` file, changing the `Exec` line from:

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome --app-id=pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia --profile-directory=Default
```

To

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app-id=pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia --profile-directory=Default
```

Comment: Good catch! Any idea why `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` is needed? I removed it from the one app I made (for svg-editor.html).

Comment: It's the shebang line, so if the execute permission is set on the file, the system knows what program to open the file with. I'd say you wouldn't need it if you were simply using the shortcut through unity or another menu interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

Replace `/opt/google/chrome/chrome` with `google-chrome`
So my Exec looked something like:

```
Exec=google-chrome --app-id=pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia --profile-directory=Default
```